# Elasticsearch - How to add or edit array of strings in a JSON object using Java?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I have userid, name and type variables as int, string and arraylist in Java respectively. I want to insert it into the elasticsearch database like this :-

```
users
{
    "userid": 5,
    "name": "test",
    "type": ["U1", "U2"]
}
```

1) How can I achieve this using Java client(high level API)?

2) How can I append to the "type" field(assuming it exists)?

example: I want to add "U3" to the "type" field so it becomes like this

```
users
{
    "userid": 5,
    "name": "test",
    "type": ["U1", "U2", "U3"]
}
```

Comment: Both of your strings are not in valid JSON format.

Comment: @LHCHIN could you please elaborate? I am unable to understand.

Comment: For example, all field names should be wrapped by double-quote. You can validate your JSON string with an validator such as [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#).

Comment: @LHCHIN edited. ignore the 'users' there

Comment: @DanteAdams can you please show your code and what have u tried and what error/issues ur facing with your code

Comment: What did you mean "insert something like this"? Did you want to serialize some object to a JSON string? Or deserialize some JSON string to an object? What is the expected input/output?

Comment: @LHCHIN In Java, I have data stored inside an object of a User class. I want to insert(+ append later) it into the elasticsearch database as a JSON. This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: @DanteAdams r u able to resolve it?

Comment: @OpsterESNinja no, i still havent found an answer

Comment: @DanteAdams let me see if I can find some time to solve it

Answer (score 1):

You can add a value to an array by using a script.

```
POST /users/_update/5
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "ctx._source.type.add(params.type)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "type" : "U3"
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from there : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html

I don't know how to use the high level API java client, sorry.